# interop error HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH) on server

Tags: c#, office365, pivot-table, office-interop

I am having a problem with my app when trying to run on the server.

In my place it works fine but when passed to the server it fails to try to create the pivotcache.

Excel has permissions on the server with the user IIS, on my computer I have Office 365 and Office 2010 on server.

please help.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6395y.png)

```
Excel.Application oApp;
            Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
            Excel.Workbook oBook;

            //Create COM Objects. Create a COM object for everything that is referenced
            oApp = new Excel.Application();
            oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Open(fileTest);
            oSheet = oBook.Sheets[1];
            //Range = oSheet.Range["A9","BN36"];
            //Excel.Worksheet oSheet2 = oBook.Worksheets.Add();
            //oSheet2.Name = "Pivot Table";

            //oApp = new Excel.Application();
            //oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Add();
            //oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            //oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Name";
            //oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Salary";

            //oSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Frank";
            //oSheet.Cells[2, 2] = 150000;

            //oSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "Ann";
            //oSheet.Cells[3, 2] = 300000;
            Excel.Range last = oSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
            Excel.Range range = oSheet.get_Range("A1", last);

            int lastUsedRow = last.Row;
            int lastUsedColumn = last.Column;
            //// now capture range of the first sheet = I will need this to create pivot table
            Excel.Range oRange = oSheet.Range["A1", "AJ708"];

            // create second sheet
            if (oApp.Application.Sheets.Count < 2)
            {
                oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oBook.Worksheets.Add();
            }
            else
            {
                oSheet = oApp.Worksheets[2];
            }
            oSheet.Name = "Resumen";

            // specify first cell for pivot table
            Excel.Range oRange2 = oSheet.Cells[1, 1];

            // create Pivot Cache and Pivot Table heres trow exception error
            Excel.PivotCache oPivotCache = (Excel.PivotCache)oBook.PivotCaches().Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, oRange);
            Excel.PivotTable oPivotTable = (Excel.PivotTable)oSheet.PivotTables().Add(PivotCache: oPivotCache, TableDestination: oRange2, TableName: "Summary");
```

Comment: Well, most likely you have used something in Office that isn't supported by Office 2010.

Comment: Hello, @FCA, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be useful here to include the call you're making that's throwing this error in the text. I realize this is already in the screenshot of the error message you're linking to. But by providing it directly in the question, you're making it easier for people to review the issue—while simultaneously making it easier for people in the future to find this question.

Comment: thanks, added the part of code

Comment: Doomed to fail, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Answer (score 1):

solved.

trying change this line

var oPivotCache = pivotCaches.Create(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, "Sheet1!$A$1:$AL$" + lastUsedRow);

the correct format to pass a range on office 2010 i think so.